# Auto center div within div.

Tags: html, css

Given the following

```
  <style>
  .container {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 15px auto 0px auto;
  }
  .square
  {
  float: left;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  display: block;
  background-image: url('commonimgs/empty_icon.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin: 2px;
  padding-top: 3%;
  margin-left: 5px;      
  }
  </style>
  <div>
  <div class="container">
      <div class="square">1R</div>
      <div class="square">2R</div>
      <div class="square">3R</div>
      <div class="square">4R</div>
      <div class="square">5R</div>
      <div class="square">6</div>
      <div class="square">7</div>
      <div class="square">8</div>
      <div class="square">9</div>
      <div class="square">10</div>      
  </div>
  </div>
```

I am trying to make a tiled layout that auto centers and adapts to screen size. What I can't figure out is how to get the `squares` to spread evenly across the `container`.

getting...

```
  +------------------------------------+
  |                                    |
  |  +------------------------------+  |
  |  |                              |  |
  |  | +----+ +----+ +----+         |  |
  |  | |    | |    | |    |         |  |
  |  | |    | |    | |    |         |  |  
  |  | +----+ +----+ +----+         |  |
  |  |                              |  |
  |  | +----+ +----+ +----+         |  |
  |  | |    | |    | |    |         |  |
  |  | |    | |    | |    |         |  |  
  |  | +----+ +----+ +----+         |  |
  |  |                              |  |
  |  | +----+ +----+ +----+         |  |
  |  | |    | |    | |    |         |  |
  |  | |    | |    | |    |         |  |  
  |  | +----+ +----+ +----+         |  |
  |  |                              |  |    
  |  +------------------------------+  |
  |                                    |
  +------------------------------------+
```

wanting

```
  +------------------------------------+
  |                                    |
  |  +------------------------------+  |
  |  |                              |  |
  |  | +----+     +----+     +----+ |  |
  |  | |    |     |    |     |    | |  |
  |  | |    |     |    |     |    | |  |  
  |  | +----+     +----+     +----+ |  |
  |  |                              |  |
  |  | +----+     +----+     +----+ |  |
  |  | |    |     |    |     |    | |  |
  |  | |    |     |    |     |    | |  |  
  |  | +----+     +----+     +----+ |  |
  |  |                              |  |
  |  | +----+     +----+     +----+ |  |
  |  | |    |     |    |     |    | |  |
  |  | |    |     |    |     |    | |  |  
  |  | +----+     +----+     +----+ |  |
  |  |                              |  |    
  |  +------------------------------+  |
  |                                    |
  +------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Does your outer container have a fixed or maximum width? In the example you've provided, resizing the page will make the boxes all appear on one line.

Comment: no, this is for mobile so screen size will vary landscape/portait

Comment: just for your curiosity, have you ever seen [foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `padding: 3%;` to `.container`

```
.container {
  overflow: hidden; 
  height: 100%;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 15px auto 0px auto;
    background:#dbdbdb;
      padding: 3%;
  }
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sJEdZ/1/)**

---

Or `text-align:center` to `.container`

```
.container {
  overflow: hidden; 
  height: 100%;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 15px auto 0px auto;
  background:#dbdbdb;
  padding: 3%; text-align:center
}
```

**[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/sJEdZ/2/)**

Also change `display:block` to `display:inline-block` in `.square`

Answer (score 1):

Use the table and create 3 columns, each column should have DIV inside. You can easily align the DIV in center by using

```
<td align="center">
```

Answer (score 0):

change or add these:

```
.square{
    position: relative;
    width: 27%;
    padding-top: 3%;
    margin-left: 4%;
    margin-right: 1%;
    margin-top: 5%;
    margin-bottom: 0%;
}
.container{
    padding-bottom: 5%;
}
```